# R: Can I plot a list instead of dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a list like this

```
good[1:2]
## [[1]]
## [1] 8 12 10 15 25 2 3 21
## [[2]]
## [1] 6 2 7 24 34 5
```

want to make a plot, using `c(1,2,3....)` as x-axile, y have two series here `good[1]` and `good[2]`, how can I do that? it seems `plot` cannot deal with list data, tried `ggplot`, not work also?

Comment: `good[[1]]` and `good[[2]]` seem to have different lengths here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `plot` for the first list element, with `lines` for the second.

```
good <- list(c(8, 12, 10, 15, 25, 2, 3, 21), c(6, 2, 7, 24, 34, 5)) 
plot(good[[1]], type = 'l', col = 'blue', ylab = "y", xlab = "x", 
     ylim = range(unlist(good)))
lines(good[[2]], col = "red")
```

[image]

Additionally, if you have more than two list elements, you can use `sapply` on `lines`

```
myList <- lapply(vector("list", 5), function(dummy){ sample(1:100, 5, TRUE) })
plot(myList[[1]], type = 'l', ylab = "y", xlab = "x", 
     ylim = range(unlist(myList)))
sapply(2:length(myList), function(x){ lines(myList[[x]], col = x) })
```

[image]